# Angular vs-repeat performance issue with tables with 7k rows

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular vs-repeat to render around 7k rows in a table. If I use vs-repeat for table body, the rendering was very slow.

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody vs-repeat style="width: 100%;">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in list track by $index">
      <td>{{::row[listColumns[0].colName]}}</td>
      <td>{{::row[listColumns[1].colName]}}</td>
      <td>{{::row[listColumns[2].colName]}}</td>
      <td>{{::row[listColumns[3].colName]}}</td>
      <td>{{::row[listColumns[4].colName]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

If I use vs-repeat without tables, in my case I used divs. Its rendering very fast

```
<div vs-repeat class="table-body">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="row in list track by $index">
    <div class="col-md-4">{{::row[listColumns[0].colName]}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">{{::row[listColumns[1].colName]}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">{{::row[listColumns[2].colName]}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">{{::row[listColumns[3].colName]}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">{{::row[listColumns[4].colName]}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please suggest how to improve performance for table?

Comment: why would you render **7 thousand!!** rows of data on a single browser page?  This is the second question in the last half hour where someone has asked to do this, and this is likely to get the same response, **this does not make sense to do**.  Use a data set and paging.

Comment: @Claies Thanks for your advice. But the service will give the result set at once. So I need to handle at front end only.

Comment: rendering 7 thousand rows is insane and I realize I do not know anything about the project requirements but are you able to use [something like this](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/404_large_data_sets_and_performance)

Comment: I would definitely talk to your backend developer to implement paging. 7k records at once does not have a good user experience

Comment: you can still receive the data into the controller and then set up paging for the rendered results; rendering the entire result set isn't a good idea at all, and the framework is not optimized to handle that amount of rendered items.

Comment: I would suggest go with paging instead showing all records at a time. You can also look at smart-table or ng-grid to render your records on UI.

Comment: But why angular vs-repeat directive is rendering divs faster than table rows?

Answer (score 1):

With vast collections of items that render many DOM elements, even the most negligible processing of items inside an `ng-repeat` can choke your app.
DOM-related solutions that check if elements are in view don't tell you if nested components have been loaded and rendered completely, leading to errors.

My solution to this problem is angular's `limitTo : limit: begin` filter, along with iScroll or native `scrollTop` and `scrollBottom` callbacks, which raise or reduce the begin index in the controller according to the browse direction - sort of frontend pagination where only a specific number of items are shown at the DOM.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo : 100 : 600 track by $index">
    <span>{{ item.property }}</span>
</tr>
```

Then you can find the optimal limitTo number that work out best for the app - while keeping it light, quick, and agile as Angular should be.

Answer (score 0):

use ng-repeat on small set of an array. Do pagination or lazy loading. store data to temporary array which you want to display rather having n-repeat on 7k records.
Thoughts?
Thanks!